# Is there a xml url for RSS Business newsfeed of Reuters or Bloomberg for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloomberg, reuters

I tried to get the xml url from "https://www.reuters.com/business". And I couldn't find the xml files for reuters and bloomberg news.

Comment: Where these the URLs that you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're looking for the *sitemap* URLs.  Here are the URLs:

- https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index1.xml
- https://www.reuters.com/sitemap_news_index2.xml
- https://www.bloomberg.com/feeds/bbiz/sitemap_news.xml